# TFS, disabled user and their pending works

Tags: tfs

I have a problem with TFS.

TFS users access by windows authority.

One user left so their user account was removed or disabled by company IT, but the user has some pending works in TFS.

Right now the user cannot use it, so the checked-out works always show 'edit' there.

I'm the TFS admin, how I can force set those works back to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2012/10/10/Removing-Another-Users-Lock-in-TFS.aspx

Essentially you are rolling back any of their changes which releases any pending locks.  After rolling back the changes as an admin you are free to delete all the workspaces associated with that user.

Comment: Posting off mobile, no formatting options on the post.  My apologies.